# Width of the popup menu - How to change

Tags: android, popup

I am using the following code for displaying pop up menus

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
                      popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popupmenu, popupMenu.getMenu());
                      popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                      item.toString(),
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                   }
                  });

                      popupMenu.show();
                  }
```

But the menu is covering a lot of my screen area. How to specify the size of the popup menu ?

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to create a custom Dialog. See the official docs on how to do this here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog